# Kept getting Index Errors with pandas data frame, now can't get correct values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am having trouble with pandas dataframe. I not able to get my values to appear correctly. I kept getting index errors but now I got my table to show and the inputs are incorrect.
This is what I am getting: [image]
I would like the second line showing 15,0,0 for Andy.
Expected output:
[image]

```
customers = [u'Becky Buyer - Address Two', u'Andy Buyer - Andy nguyen']
plu_parts = [12834L, 11521L, 11164L]
cases = numpy.zeros(shape=(len(plu_parts),len(customers)))
```

Here I wrote:

```
 for i in range(len(plu_parts)):
        for j in range(len(customers)):
            plu_sets = [x for x in obs_plu_code_buyer if x['seller_inventory__plu_code_id'] == plu_parts[i] and x['purchase_order_line__purchase_order__buyer__company_name'] + str(" - ") + x['purchase_order_line__purchase_order__delivery_address__contact'] == customers[j]]
            print(plu_sets)
            if len(plu_sets) > 0:
                cases[i][j] = int(plu_sets[0]['num_cases'])
```

Which gives me

```
cases =  [[ 100.   10.]
 [  13.    0.]
 [  50.    0.]]



veggies = [u'Conventional Any Custom Mix , 90% Iceberg w/ carrot and red cabbage , 4/5#', u'Conventional Cabbage , Green , 45#', u'Conventional Cabbage , Napa , 15#']


dd  = 'Delivery Dated ' + delivery_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
py = pd.DataFrame({dd :customers})
for k in range(0,len(veggies)):
    d = [int(row) for row in cases[:,0]]
    py.insert(k+1,veggies[k],d[k])
```

All help is appreciated.
EDIT: Included reprex code

Comment: Can you show your desired result?

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired output?

Comment: Yeah the second line with Andy Buyer should be 10,0,0 @JoaoSalles

Comment: your cases variable is lacking some commas

Comment: hmm I gave it a shot and got "Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'Delivery Dated 10/01/2020' was passed" @G.Anderson

Comment: @JoaoSalles my cases is actually `cases = numpy.zeros(shape=(len(plu_parts),len(customers)))`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Comment: @AMC Got it. Updated

Comment: @AndyNguyen What are your *correct* values that you expect? Can you include an output dataframe?

Comment: @DavidErickson Added!

Comment: This code is not reproducible. For example, I would receive `NameError: name 'obs_plu_code_buyer' is not defined` if I used your code.

Comment: @DavidErickson It is a whole lot of code through my django objects that leads up to that. Am I suppose to copy all of it? I thought the outcome of cases would have been sufficient

Comment: @AndyNguyen you are just trying to create a dataframe? Also, the output of cases is a list of lists. Shouldn't there be coammas?

Comment: @DavidErickson Yeah I am just trying to get my dataframe to present correctly

Comment: @DavidErickson The output is the result of numpy.zeros()

Comment: @AndyNguyen that is how it is supposed to look though, correct?

Comment: @DavidErickson Right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.T` to transpose the numpy array `cases` upon creation of your dataframe:

---

```
customers = [u'Becky Buyer - Address Two', u'Andy Buyer - Andy nguyen']
plu_parts = ['12834L', '11521L', '11164L']
cases = np.array([[100., 10.],
       [13., 0.],
       [50., 0.]])
veggies = [u'Conventional Any Custom Mix , 90% Iceberg w/ carrot and red cabbage , 4/5#', u'Conventional Cabbage , Green , 45#', u'Conventional Cabbage , Napa , 15#']
dd  = 'Delivery Dated 10/01/2020'
df = pd.DataFrame(cases.T, columns=veggies, index=customers)
df.index.name = dd
df
```

[image]

Comment: Hm strange.. Everything is great but the column with delivery date and customers arent showing

Comment: Not sure and not at my computer. Forget about creating the index in the data frame and try: df['Delivery Dated 10/01/2020'] = customers THEN On the next line.... df=df.set_index('Delivery Dated 10/01/2020')

Comment: I just did a df.insert(0,dd,customers). One more question! You seem to be really good at this thats why. How would I be able to add a row at the end. for a "Totals" kind of thing I already have all the data for it

Comment: @AndyNguyen Make the last row an individual data frame called let’s say ‘totals’ with the same index name and same column headers. Then do df=df.append(‘totals’)

Comment: Ah I am starting to catch on now. Learned a lot today. Thanks a lot brother